Design of a controller G(s) which places the poles of CL system in a certain region
I have this control systems request: for the open loop process $$P(s)=\frac{(s+1)(s+2)}{(s-2)^2(s+3)}$$ find a controller with dimension less or equal than 1 sucht that the closed-loop system $$W(s)=\frac{PG(s)}{1+PG(s)}$$ has all real poles in the interval $$[-3,2]$$
From the analysis of the root locus I deduce that it is not possible to satisfy the request with a proportional action $$G(s)=K$$ so I decided to chosse a parametric controller $$G(s)=\frac{as+b}{s+1}$$ which first of all simplifies the zero on the numerator which is negative and so is legit.
Then I impose that $$NUM(1+PG(s))=(s-2)^2(s+3)+(as+b)(s+2)=(s-\alpha)(s-\beta)(s-\gamma)$$ where $$\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in [-3,2]$$ but imposing the conditions on the polynomials coefficients I cannot find any value for which this is possible.

Looking at the root locus plot, we see that there is a branch that goes to the left starting at the pole at \$s=-3\$.

To nullify this the controller needs a zero at \$s=-3\$. This system with can be made stable with an appropriate choice of \$k\$.
To make the controller proper, we also need to add a pole. If the pole is to the left of \$s=-2\$ then that branch will go to the left of \$s=-3\$.
Thus any controller \$k\frac{s+3}{s+p}\$ with \$p\leq2\$ and appropriate choice of \$k\$ will satisfy your requirements.
For example \$5\frac{s + 3}{s + 2}\$ will give you a stable system with no real poles.
\$7.5\frac{s + 3}{s}\$ will give a stable system with the real pole at \$s=-0.6\$
etc.

I accidentaly wrote 2 instead of -2 in the exercise. I meant real zeroes in $$[-3,-2]$$. Does it change anything?
